# Python3 ifxPy memory leak

Tags: python, memory-leaks, informix

I created a linux service by using systemd. My service call Python script. This script call a function in infinity loop every 30 seconds I'm using `time.sleep(30)` to loop every 30 seconds. My script open a connection on Informix database, read data, insert data in local MongoDB, call web services.

But the service memory never decrease. The memory increase every time. If I restart my service the memory is totally released. The service start at 19MB and after 14 hours 555MB.

Here is my code :

```
def populate_app():
    ifx_connection = IfxPy.connect(ifx_param, "", "")
    stmt = IfxPy.exec_immediate(ifx_connection, sql)
    dictionary = IfxPy.fetch_assoc(stmt) # Get data key / value

    ...

    IfxPy.close(ifx_connection)

while True:
    populate_app()
    time.sleep(30)
```

Does the memory leak is probably due to `request`, `ifxPy` or `pymongo` libraries ?

I commented all my code inside my loop and I let just these two lines in the populate_app function :

```
ifx_connection = IfxPy.connect(ifx_param, "", "")
stmt = IfxPy.exec_immediate(ifx_connection, sql)
```

So the memory doesn't increase. Then I put this line :

```
dictionary = IfxPy.fetch_assoc(stmt) # Get data key / value
```

And the memory leak is here again. So there is a problem with ifxPy I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try releasing the result-set memory calling free_result()?

Something like:

```
....
....
# Bulk insert
if new_users:
    user.insert_many(new_users)
if error_user_data:
    user_error.insert_many(error_user_data)

IfxPy.free_result(stmt)
IfxPy.close(ifx_connection)
```

Comment: Oh it works like a charm thank you so much. So we always need to force clear memory with `free_result` ?

Comment: Does I need to use `free_stmt ` too ?

Comment: If your script is suppose to be alive all the time, I think is a good idea to clean up (free) as much resources as you can after you are done with them. It can only make it go faster ;)